# ajax with ui:insert in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have JSF page as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
      ...
    </h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
      <div id="VERTICAL_MENU">
          <ul id="menu" class="mainMenu">
             <li><div class="noSub"></div><h:commandLink action="customerVoice.xhtml"><h2>contact</h2><f:ajax render="ContentLoader" /></h:commandLink></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="INNER_CONTENT_ROW" >
  <h:panelGroup id="ContentLoader" >
       <div id="CONTENT_CONTAINER">
           <ui:insert name="ContentPage" >Default Content</ui:insert>
       </div>
   </h:panelGroup>
</div>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

I want load the `<ui:insert>` content by `<f:ajax>`, but it does not work.

The desired content is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:composition template="/parentBranches.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="ContentPage" >
            <div id="pageContent" >
                <div id="TITLE" ><h1 class="tBox" ><h:outputText value="در دست ساخت" /></h1></div>
                <div class="fullClear" ></div>
                <div class="UP_BUttON" >
                    <h:commandLink ><img src="images/feed.png" class="feedButton" /></h:commandLink>
                    <h:commandLink ><img src="images/printer.png" class="printButton" /></h:commandLink>
                </div>
                <div class="fullClear" ></div>
                <div id="CONTEXT" >
                    <div class="cImg" ><h:graphicImage url="images/sample.png" /></div>
                    <h:outputText value="content" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

When I click the link, no action is done and page content does not change.

Comment: LOL, why are you asking for a private answer :P. Are you developing an "xxx" site haha ^^. Anyway, please post what you have tried and what kind of errors or weird behaviors that you got.

Comment: no it is a more important that xxx site. when the content page is like this

Comment: of course :P, I was just kidding!

Comment: I know :) . I want explain it for you but it does not possible by comment so I edit my question

Comment: hmm... what are you expecting to happen when you click which link? Besides, your `commandLink` does not have any `action` or `actionListener`. You need to tell it what to do

Comment: commandLink in first code has an action with ajax tag, when it is clicked, the page of code 2 should be open in the group panel with id="ContentLoader". but when I click it, no action is done ore when the action is done it reload page javascript files

Answer (score 1):

JSF's `<ui:insert>` is used in creating templates. According to your code, I think the 1st piece of code is the template `parentBranches.xhtml`. And the 2nd piece of code is the template client `customerVoice.xhtml` which used the above template. In brief, `template + template client = page`. If you want to open `customerVoice.xhtml` page, you have to navigate to that page. You cannot do it with Ajax.

In general, I can think of 2 ways to achieve your goal:

1. Don't use Ajax by removing the whole `<f:ajax>` and leave it as:

   ```
   <h:commandLink action="customerVoice"><h2>contact</h2></h:commandLink>
   ```
2. Use [`<ui:include>`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/).

   - In your 1st .xhtml page, you can change the `ContentLoader` portion to something like this:

     ```
     <h:panelGroup id="ContentLoader" >
        <div id="CONTENT_CONTAINER">
           <ui:include src="#{mrBean.page}" />
        </div>
     </h:panelGroup>
     ```
   - Change your link like the following:

     ```
     <h:commandLink actionListener="#{mrBean.openPage('customerVoice.xhtml')}"
                    value="contact" style="font-size: large">
        <f:ajax render="ContentLoader" />
     </h:commandLink>
     ```
   - Create a `ManagedBean` to control the content. It should be like this:

     ```
     @ManagedBean
     @RequestScoped
     public class MrBean {
        private String page;

        public MrBean() {
           this.page = "The link to the page that contains your default content";
        }

        public void openPage(String thePage) {
           this.page = thePage;
        }
     }
     ```

You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718727/rendering-only-a-fragment-of-the-page/8724525#8724525) for another example about `<ui:include>`. This [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/) from *Mkyong.com* may also be useful to you.

**UPDATE:** This is a test page for you to try out:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body >
        <h:form id="form"> 
            <h:commandLink actionListener="#{mrBean.openPage('Full URL to your customerVoice.xhtml')}"
                           value="contact" style="font-size: large">
                <f:ajax render="ContentLoader" />
            </h:commandLink>

            <h:panelGroup id="ContentLoader" >
                <div id="CONTENT_CONTAINER">
                    <ui:include src="#{mrBean.page}" />
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup> 

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I test your code but it does not work on my page. I get this error     <f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'ContentLoader' - cannot locate it in the context of the component...

Comment: @user997719 I have no idea where you did wrongly. There shouldn't be any issues with my code. I updated my answer with a very simple Test.xhtml page. Replace what you need to in this page and the above bean code and try out. I have no problem running it.