# JSF View rendering in nested Tab

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Let say I have a screen with 3 tabs:
Tab1 - Tab2 - Tab3

The Tab2 has 2 nested tabs:
Tab2
Admin Client

The Client tab includes 3 screens but displays one screen at a time:
ClientList.xhtml => ClientUpdate.xhtml => ClientDetail.xhml

The user navigates within the Client Tab container thru the 3 previous screens.

Let's say Client.xhtml has the following action to navigate to ClientUpdate.xhtml

```
<h:commandButton action="#{clientBean.clientUpdate()}"/...>

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ClientBean{

public String clientUpdate(){
return "ClientUpdate"
}
```

How do I force the application to render the ClientUpdate.xhtml within the Tab2 container without refreshing the entire page and losing the tab in focus (pattern/Framework)?

I am using Jquery and JSF2.0 . I am trying to implement that without using Primefaces or Richfaces for now but could if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

- Primefaces Tabview will take care of the dynamic content loading with ajax.
- ui:include with a backing bean as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718727/rendering-only-a-fragment-of-the-page) to load different content.